# Adding a new branch to a tree then adding the new leaf to the right place in a linked list in an efficient way

Tags: c, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

Suppose we have a binary tree and a linked list that holds the data that appears in all of the leafs.

For example, the following tree's list would be: `9,2,3` (order matter, left to right)

[image]

Now we add a new node somewhere, thus creating a new branch, like so:

[image]

Is there an efficient way to add this new leaf to list such that the list will keep the order of the leafs from left to right? i.e the new list is supposed to be `9,1,2,3`.

Anything I come up with, in the worst case scenario, is the same as making a completely new list, i.e, traversing the whole tree.

Like traversing the tree in LDR and looking for the new leaf while keeping the info of the last leaf, but it could go through all or most of the tree in the worst case scenario.

BTW the list and tree are arbitrarily defined like so:

```
typedef struct listNode  {
    int data;
    struct listNode* next;
} ListNode;

typedef struct  treeNode {
    int data;
    struct treeNode* parent; //prev node
    struct treeNode* left;
    struct treeNode* right;
} TreeNode;
```

Comment: You'll also have to account for node removal, for example if 9 gets a child node.  Intuitively it seems like each interior node should keep handles to the first and last nodes in the leaf list corresponding to their subtree, so you could narrow your search as you traverse down to wherever you're inserting the new node.

Comment: @MattOlson yes that's actually an easy case, if we know we add a leaf to a leaf then we just need to overwrite the data in the corresponding place in the list.

Comment: @MattOlson about the other part, do you mean that for example, in the original tree, `2` should hold `9` and `3`?

Comment: No; for example, 8 would hold pointers to 9 and 3 (the bounds of its subtree); 5 would hold 9 and 2; 7 would hold `null` and 2 (it has no leaves on its left subtree), and so on.  Then when you get to 7 you add 1 in the right place (perhaps you want a doubly-linked list) and propagate changes back up the tree as you unwind the stack.  I'm just brainstorming; If I come up with a concrete algorithm I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Or you could use @amit's solution, which is much more straightforward than what I had in mind. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is, but it will also require adding some more data to `treeNode`, a pointer to the list node (if such exist).

Now, the idea is once you have found where to add the new node (`v`), and let's say it is a son of some node `u`.

You need to find the previous leaf. It can be done in `O(h)` by going up on the tree, until you have found a node `x` that has a left son. Go to the left son, and keep traversing on it, in the following order:

```
if the current node has right son:
     go to right son, repeat
else if the current node has left son:
     go to left son, repeat
else:
     found previous leaf, let it be l
```

Now, you have the new node `v`, and the previous leaf `l`.

All you have to do now is to put v's node after l's node:

```
v.node = createNode();
v.node.next = l.node.next; 
l.node.next = v.node;
```

Complexity of this algorithm is `O(h)`, where `h` is the height of the tree.

Note: Take care of the simple edge case where `v` is the first node in the linked list.

Comment: Going up the tree, nice! If the tree didn't have the `parent` definition then the best solution would be to just make a new list then?

Comment: What are the odds that two Amits answer the same the question lol.

Comment: @kuhaku No, if you didn't have the `parent` - you could still "find" it, because you inserted the element (I assume) recursively from the root, so you can climb back on the stack and getting the `parent` you need.